# What is the proper proposition for "to reconfigure"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, differences

[Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reconfigure) has seemingly mentioned nothing, as I checked.

Could you please clear which sentence is sound:

1- The system must be reconfigured **to** another mode.

2- The system must be reconfigured **into** another mode.

3- The system must be reconfigured **onto** another mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Into*** appears to be the more common preposition according to  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reconfigure%20to%2Creconfigure%20into%2Creconfigured%20onto&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creconfigure%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creconfigure%20into%3B%2Cc0). (Note that in most cases "reconfigure to" is followed by a verb.)

From [Ubuntu Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-how-to-reconfigure-x-windows-system-xorg-server/):

> - Just follow on screen questions and you should able to restore or ***reconfigure to previous state.***

From [Chip multiprocessor architecture](https://books.google.it/books?id=spZZDwuAgUYC&pg=PA51&dq=%22reconfigure%20into%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwxLjb_ZHUAhUIBMAKHTuYAVUQ6AEIJTAB#v=onepage&q=%22reconfigure%20into%22&f=false) :

> - After benchmark capture, the traces were used to drive a relatively fast system simulator that ***was parameterized to be able to reconfigure into the wide variety of configurations*** needed for the study.

From [Robotics](https://books.google.it/books?id=3TtSAAAAMAAJ&q=%22reconfigure%20into%22&dq=%22reconfigure%20into%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw5rWO_pHUAhUKL8AKHYZRA3oQ6AEIOjAF):

> - Self-repair, a special type of self-reconfiguration, could allow a robot to replace damaged units with fresh units, ***or to reconfigure into a different shape*** in order to continue with the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks. You have a little typo by the way: "Robitics" should have been Robotics.